# Python CPLEX records feasible solution

Tags: python, callback, cplex

I would like to know how to use MIP callback in Python CPLEX API to record feasible solution. Currently my cplex model can run for 10 hours and it seems that the objective value didn't improve at all, however I couldn't stop halfway since the data will be lost, so I'd like to know how to use callback in an MILP problem to record feasible solution

**Edit**: I'm not using docplex, I used cplex

```
import cplex
```

Answer (score 0):

see the progress listener example at https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/blob/master/examples/mp/jupyter/progress.ipynb

> This tutorial includes everything you need to set up decision
> optimization engines, build a mathematical programming model, then use
> the progress listeners to monitor progress, capture intermediate
> solutions and stop the solve on your own criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I'm not using docplex, I'm just using Cplex, would you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: There is no off-the-shelf solution in Cplex/Python. You'd have to subclass the `MIPInfoCallback` class, check that an incumbent solution exists when it is called, then extract the value vector and work from there. This said,  can you explain as why you'd rather use the index-based Python API instead of DOcplex? On th eopposite, Docplex has an off-the-shelf class to do excatly what you need: `docplex.mp.progress.SolutionRecorder`